# With ojdbc6 getMetaData() on resultset spikes in number of sql's executed, dont see this with ojdbc5

Tags: oracle, jdbc, metadata

we use getMetaData() on every cursor returned from the oracle stored procedure call.

With ojdbc5 we dont have spike in number of metadata sql's executed and average time. But with ojdbc6 we see spike in number of metadata sql's executed and increase in avg sql execution time.

Does anyone know or aware of this issue with ojdbc6.. wish they had made it open source?

did anyone atleast try decompiling the ojdbc6 jar anytime?

Comment: Can you tell what it's doing by querying V$SQL?

Comment: we decompiled it and found that for every one procedure call, the getMetadata is making two sql executions (one for proc related meta and other for paramaters of proc)...we even hav trace files and looks like its the lethal combination of generic dao programming that uses metadata... the killer here is Spring + Ojdbc... yeah i know everyone is using spring but no one has noticed this.   Is there a generic dao program that doesnt use metadata.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the way SimpleJdbcCall of Spring works, it gets the metadata of the procedure and its arguments for everycall. even though they should not cache it, there should have been a setting which enables and disables the caching of the metadata while using SimpleJdbcCall.

When using the SimpleJdbcCall... beware of the metadata contention that happens.. if your app has too many pl/sql procedure invocations then the oracle can get latch contention and hence the overall app will slow down as this causes a bottleneck... servers even crash rendering the app non-responsive. add a small cache by diving into spring code and make a flag to enable/disable... tadaanngggg.. it works awesomely faster than ever.